# Parse variables into echo string

Tags: php, echo, fopen

I'm trying to use PHP variables into echoed file, and couldn't get where is a trouble at first using that script:

```
$head = new mod_head("head.php");
$id="ASDSSgdfsfsdfS";
echo $head;
```

mod_head class:

```
class mod_head
{
private $out="";
function __construct($arg)
{
$this->out=$this->parts($arg);
}
public function __toString()
{
return $this->out;
}
private function parts($file)
{
return fread(@fopen(PATH . "parts/".$file, 'r'), filesize(PATH . "parts/".$file));
}
}
```

and the file is "head.php"

```
<h1><center style="background:orange; border-radius:15px;">LOGO</center></h1>
<br><?php print_r($id)?>
<div>BANNER <div>$id <?php echo $id ;?></div></div>
```

i dont want to create global vars, why it doest echo $id var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're going to need to parse the file, not just read it.  The second problem you'll have is a scope issue.  `$id` is outside of the scope of the `parts()` function.  In order to return the contents of the required file instead of just printing it I've used the [output control functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Try changing your parts function to this:

```
private function parts($file)
{
    ob_start();
    require(PATH . "parts/".$file);
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

To fix the scope issue try changing `$id="ASDSSgdfsfsdfS";` to `$head->id = "ASDSSgdfsfsdfS";`, then change head.php to be the following:

```
<h1><center style="background:orange; border-radius:15px;">LOGO</center></h1>
<br><?php print_r($this->id)?>
<div>BANNER <div>$id <?php echo $this->id ;?></div></div>
```

Comment: You are awesome~!! but it is impossible to write `$head->id = "something"` from script, where i creating new object :(

Comment: i think i could make it throught array, with is adding by magic method `__set($name, $value)` but array needs extra memory, but there is no any another exit, in my opinion.

Comment: anyway i cannot get` $this->data[id] ` into my html/php page ((

Comment: My solution won't work too well if you can't modify the main page.  The only other option would be to add `global $id;` to your `parts()` function, but that's not a fix, just a hack.  You'd have to add all the variables you plan on using in any other included header files.

Comment: Iv found my bug, the mistake was into `__construct()` calling `parts()` function should be after variables defination... Anyway your answer is the best

Answer (score 1):

Simply reading a file with fread will not parse any PHP contained inside. Perhaps you are looking for something like:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Using require() is basically like copying and pasting the required file directly where your require() statement is. This means that the required file would only be able to use variables that are within the scope of where the require() statement is.

Comment: I dont want to print data instantly, im going to agregate and after througt __tostring() method print the result, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using ob_start() and friends. Perhaps you would be better off using an already fleshed out open-source PHP "Framework".

Comment: @user1112984 I've documented in my answer the process of using the output buffer to return the output instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are reading the contents of `head.php` and echoing them verbatim; nowhere do you make PHP compile and run that file as code. You could do that using `include('head.php')`, but that would not work blindly because you also have to make sure that `$id` *is in scope* at the point you do the `include`.

However that's not as easy as it sounds because it is not possible to automatically "pack the whole local scope" for later use because automatically implies code inside a function, and the very act of calling that function causes the scope to change.

Comment: Thanks Alot! Iv make like that  
 include(PATH . "parts/".$file); in parts function, but i want to storage it in memory, also i coundnt return include. Is there are any way to avoid data print?

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that you are probably using mod_head is passing in a php file  so it can be used as a view, right?

if thats the case, usually there is also a way to include a variable so that way it exists in the other file, head.php.. since there isn't one, you'd need to create a method for that. and then make that fread an include or require instead.

If not, and you're simply loading the file, the other comments about fread not parsing is totally correct and you will not be able to simply access $id from the other file.

Comment: mod_head is using fread() to read the file, thus not parsing any contained PHP.